# Datatables deleting a row where column value equals something

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have tried the following and I am unable to find a match. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();

//hide the row where text in column 1 equals 202733001010
                var index = table.row().eq( 0 ).filter( function (rowIdx) {
                    return table.cell( rowIdx, 0 ).data() === '202733001010' ? true : false;
                } );
```

What i get is a convoluted empty array that does not seem to have any values in it. My end purpose is to delete a row where a column cell (in this case 0) equals a certain value but I think I may be using an incorrect approach. Many thanks in advance for your suggestions.  Datatables documentation : https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

Comment: Do you mean a column or do you mean a cell in column 1 row x.

Comment: Cell in column. Sorry I updated my question above.

Comment: Do you want to hide or delete the cell and which version of datatable are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to actually remove the row (filter and search just hides/shows matching data), the logic below can do it fairly straight forward. I use a text box to enter a value to get ride of out of the first column. If found, I remove it.

See it work here http://live.datatables.net/natejiju/1/edit

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $("#btnGo").on("click", function(){

        var s =  $("#txtSearch").val();
        table.rows().nodes().each(function(a,b) {
            if($(a).children().eq(0).text() == s){
               table.rows(a).remove();
             }
          } );


          table.rows().invalidate();
          table.draw();
        });

      });
```